# Node+supertest flakes with "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

Tags: node.js, ssl, port, supertest

My node tests are randomly failing  “Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established” and I’ve been debugging this for weeks. What’s going wrong? I’m using supertest

Answer (score 1):

Tldr; Don’t rely on supertest to call listen and close on your server.  Call server.listen before calling supertest.agent and handle calling close on your own.

Useful reading: https://gavv.github.io/articles/ephemeral-port-reuse/

The sockets created by net.Server.listen have the SO_REUSEADDR flag added to them. This means there can be multiple binds to the same port as along as they all add the SO_REUSEADDR flag.

Supertest by default will call server.listen(0) which creates and ipv6 socket on an ephemeral port using SO_REUSEADDR.

When you later use supertest to talk to your local server, it seems to prefer connecting over ipv4 instead of ipv6. And that’s ok at least on Macs because if dual-stacking, I.e. binding to “::” on ipv6 also listens to the same port on ipv4 if it isn’t taken by some other process.

However, every once in a while there can exist another process listening on the ipv4 version of the ephemeral port that’s being used by the test (SO_REUSEADDR  allows this). The dual stacking logic from above will choose the ipv4 socket to a random process over the ipv6 socket that’s actually from your test.

There’s a million reasons why this shouldn’t work and the foreign process closes its end before the TLS handshake finishes, randomly giving you the error in the question.   Thankfully, if your server is already listening when you call supertest.agent, supertest no longer tries to be smart about implicitly calling listen/close and you can use a fixed port outside of the ephemeral range to avoid all of this.